# Formatting Youtube iFrame Embed and Maintain Black Side Bars

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Problem:
I would like the Youtube player that **maintains the black bars on the side** that prevent the video from getting too big. This is what Youtube does with videos on their site. However, when I use the embed, the video take up 100% width.

[I am currently using react-youtube for their Youtube component.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube)

**Player implementation**

```
const opts = {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',

    playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
    },
}

<YouTube videoId={heroVideo.videoId} 
  opts={opts} 
  onEnd={() => finishedVideo(heroVideo, playlistDisplay, playlistIndex, videos)}/>
```

**Player styling**

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    /*padding-top: 25px;*/
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;

}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Pictures for reference. Both the same video, same screen width.

**Desired video display behavior. On youtube.com**
[image: problem image]

**Incorrect video display. On my app**
[image]

**Another reference to video display I'm looking for**
[image: Another reference on neverthink.tv]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution so far (barring any bugs I find) was to update the CSS.

**Remove padding-bottom and set height to 100%.**

```
.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
height: 100%; 
display: block;
background-color: black;
```

}